# Host unreachable when pairing Visual Studio to Mac mini

Tags: visual-studio

When I tried pairing Visual Studio to Mac mini, the connecting failed and the error is "Host unreachable". Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. The two machine are not in the oen network. Thanks!